# как запустить в цикле много threading одновременно, а не последовательно?

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

Пример функции которую хочу положить в нить (не принципиально, но как раз при работе с сетью появляются задержки время которых хочу использовать на выполнение остальных задач, поэтому тут requests.get):

```
def func(art):
    page = requests.get('https://сайт' + art + '&locale=ru_RU',
                        timeout=25).content
    title_ = bs(page, features='html.parser').find('div', class_='ds-header-content-product-description').text
    return title_
```

Первая функция запускает нити "одновременно" и работает как надо.
*(Используя свободное процессорное время на реквестах)*:

```py
def threads20(func, List):
    import os
    if not os.path.exists('pomo_timely_files'):
        os.mkdir('pomo_timely_files')


    delitel = round(len(List) / 20)

    count = 1
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    list4 = []
    list5 = []
    list6 = []
    list7 = []
    list8 = []
    list9 = []
    list10 = []
    list11 = []
    list12 = []
    list13 = []
    list14 = []
    list15 = []
    list16 = []
    list17 = []
    list18 = []
    list19 = []
    list20 = []
    # print(List)

    for q in List:
        if count <= delitel:
            list1.append(q)
        # print(list1)

        if (2 * delitel) >= count > delitel:
            list2.append(q)
        # print(list2)

        if (3 * delitel) >= count > (2 * delitel):
            list3.append(q)
        # print(list3)

        if (4 * delitel) >= count > (3 * delitel):
            list4.append(q)
        # print(list4)

        if (5 * delitel) >= count > (4 * delitel):
            list5.append(q)
        # print(list5)

        if (6 * delitel) >= count > (5 * delitel):
            list6.append(q)
        # print(list6)

        if (7 * delitel) >= count > (6 * delitel):
            list7.append(q)
        # print(list7)

        if (8 * delitel) >= count > (7 * delitel):
            list8.append(q)
        # print(list8)

        if (9 * delitel) >= count > (8 * delitel):
            list9.append(q)
        # print(list9)

        if (10 * delitel) >= count > (9 * delitel):
            list10.append(q)
        # print(list10)

        if (11 * delitel) >= count > (10 * delitel):
            list11.append(q)
        # print(list11)

        if (12 * delitel) >= count > (11 * delitel):
            list12.append(q)
        # print(list12)

        if (13 * delitel) >= count > (12 * delitel):
            list13.append(q)
            # print(list13)

        if (14 * delitel) >= count > (13 * delitel):
            list14.append(q)
            # print(list14)

        if (15 * delitel) >= count > (14 * delitel):
            list15.append(q)
            # print(list15)

        if (16 * delitel) >= count > (15 * delitel):
            list16.append(q)
            # print(list16)

        if (17 * delitel) >= count > (16 * delitel):
            list17.append(q)
            # print(list17)

        if (18 * delitel) >= count > (17 * delitel):
            list18.append(q)
            # print(list18)

        if (19 * delitel) >= count > (18 * delitel):
            list19.append(q)
            # print(list19)

        if count > (19 * delitel):
            list20.append(q)
            # print(list20)

        count += 1

    def forOneList(OneList, NumberFile):
        time_old = time.time()
        l = []
        for q in OneList:
            res = func(q)
            l.append(res)
        write_j(l, 'pomo_timely_files/file'+str(NumberFile)+'.json')
        current_time = time.time() - time_old
        # print( current_time)

    listOfItems1 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list1, 1,))
    listOfItems2 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list2, 2,))
    listOfItems3 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list3, 3,))
    listOfItems4 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list4, 4,))
    listOfItems5 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list5, 5,))
    listOfItems6 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list6, 6,))
    listOfItems7 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list7, 7,))
    listOfItems8 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list8, 8,))
    listOfItems9 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list9, 9,))
    listOfItems10 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list10, 10,))
    listOfItems11 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list11, 11,))
    listOfItems12 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list12, 12,))
    listOfItems13 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list13, 13,))
    listOfItems14 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list14, 14,))
    listOfItems15 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list15, 15,))
    listOfItems16 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list16, 16,))
    listOfItems17 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list17, 17,))
    listOfItems18 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list18, 18,))
    listOfItems19 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list19, 19,))
    listOfItems20 = threading.Thread(target=forOneList, args=(list20, 20,))
    listOfItems1.start()
    listOfItems2.start()
    listOfItems3.start()
    listOfItems4.start()
    listOfItems5.start()
    listOfItems6.start()
    listOfItems7.start()
    listOfItems8.start()
    listOfItems9.start()
    listOfItems10.start()
    listOfItems11.start()
    listOfItems12.start()
    listOfItems13.start()
    listOfItems14.start()
    listOfItems15.start()
    listOfItems16.start()
    listOfItems17.start()
    listOfItems18.start()
    listOfItems19.start()
    listOfItems20.start()

    listOfItems1.join()
    listOfItems2.join()
    listOfItems3.join()
    listOfItems4.join()
    listOfItems5.join()
    listOfItems6.join()
    listOfItems7.join()
    listOfItems8.join()
    listOfItems9.join()
    listOfItems10.join()
    listOfItems11.join()
    listOfItems12.join()
    listOfItems13.join()
    listOfItems14.join()
    listOfItems15.join()
    listOfItems16.join()
    listOfItems17.join()
    listOfItems18.join()
    listOfItems19.join()
    listOfItems20.join()

    lis1 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file1.json')
    lis2 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file2.json')
    lis3 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file3.json')
    lis4 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file4.json')
    lis5 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file5.json')
    lis6 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file6.json')
    lis7 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file7.json')
    lis8 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file8.json')
    lis9 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file9.json')
    lis10 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file10.json')
    lis11 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file11.json')
    lis12 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file12.json')
    lis13 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file13.json')
    lis14 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file14.json')
    lis15 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file15.json')
    lis16 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file16.json')
    lis17 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file17.json')
    lis18 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file18.json')
    lis19 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file19.json')
    lis20 = read_j('pomo_timely_files/file20.json')


    listOfItems = lis1 + lis2 + lis3 + lis4 + lis5 + lis6 + lis7 + lis8 + lis9 + lis10 + lis11 + lis12 + lis13 + lis14 + lis15 + lis16 + lis17 + lis18 + lis19 + lis20
    return listOfItems
```

Во второй пытаюсь написать тоже самое, но что бы он запускал нить для каждого элемента. что бы не прописывать одни и те же строчки как писал на веху, *но работает последовательно*:

```py
def threads(func, List):
    import os

    def preparing(one, c):
        print('start '+str(c))
        res = func(one)
        write_j(res, 'pomo_timely_files/f' + str(c) + '.json')
        print('finish '+str(c))

    c = 0
    for i in List:
        res = threading.Thread(target=preparing, args=(i, c,))
        res.start()
        res.join()
        c +=1

    list_of_files = os.listdir('pomo_timely_files')
    print(list_of_files)
    list_res = []
    for file in list_of_files:
        File = pomo.read_j('pomo_timely_files/'+file)
        list_res.append(File)

    return(list_res)


print(threads(func, arts))
```

Как написать так что бы он *запускал все нити* для каждого элемента в списке *"одновременно"*?
Спасибо.

Функции чтения записи json которые в коде (просто для удобства их создал):

```py
def read_j(file_name, encod='utf8'):
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding=encod) as f:
        F = json.load(f)
        return F


def write_j(data, file_name, type='w', indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, encod='utf8'):
    with open(file_name, type, encoding=encod) as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=indent, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii)
```

Comment: А это зачем `res.join()`? Оно ведь не дает сделать следующую итерацию, пока не завершится функцию. И мне кажется, у вас нужно какой-нибудь ThreadPool использовать

Comment: Вы правы! Теперь работает!

Comment: что бы она дождалась записи всех файлов в папку. написал что бы проверяла количество в папке с к количеством в элементов в листе. когда будет ровно можно идти дальше.     while len(list_of_files) != len(List):
        list_of_files = os.listdir('pomo_timely_files')

Comment: Почему то у меня получается работать через запись файлов. как по другому передавать результат функции пока что не понял..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) чтоб запускать и [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) чтоб ждать и получать результаты (без промежуточных файлов):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    for i in List:
        futures.append(executor.submit(func, i))
    
    # ждем, когда закончат выполняться задачи
    list_res = []
    for future in futures:
        list_res.append(future.result())
```

Comment: Спасибо больше, Roman! Очень лаконичное решение. Хорошая библиотека.

Answer (score 0):

> А это зачем res.join()? Оно ведь не дает сделать следующую итерацию,
> пока не завершится функцию. – gil9red

```
c = 0
for i in List:
    res = threading.Thread(target=preparing, args=(i, c,))
    res.start()
    # res.join() # Убрал. теперь работает. Спасибою
    c +=1
```

Только не забудьте что бы он дальше не пошел нужно для последней нити .join() написать как то или написать цикл while что бы пошел дальше только когда весь список будет обработан или другими словами когда все потоки завершаться. я написал так:

```
while len(list_of_files) != len(List):
    list_of_files = os.listdir('pomo_timely_files')
```