# Выставить очередь для потока

Tags: python, многопоточность, multiprocessing, threading

У меня есть код в котором будет около 15-20 функций которые я хочу выполнять параллельно(многопоточно), но проблема в том что если я понимаю что если я запущу одновременно на компьютере 20 функций, у меня не вывезет ни оперативка ни процессор, поэтому я хочу прописать очередь для потоков по принципу FIFO, выполняя одновременно не 15-20 потоков, а по 4, но я не совсем понимаю как это реализовать, попробовал вот так, но у меня второй процесс даже не запустился

```
if __name__ ==  "__main__": 
    thread1 = Thread(target = func1)
    thread1.start()
    while True:
        if thread1.is_alive() == True:
            time.sleep(5)
         else:
             thread5 = Thread(target = func5)
             thread5.join()
```

Можете помочь разобраться как это сделать хотя бы примерно? Исходный код выглядит вот так:

```
if __name__ ==  "__main__": 
    thread1 = Thread(target = func1)
    thread2 = Thread(target = func2)
    thread3 = Thread(target = func3)
    thread4 = Thread(target = func4)

    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    thread4.start()
```

Comment: То что вы ищете называется thread pool: `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` или `ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)`

Comment: Тут есть пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322681/218971

Comment: То есть мне нужно просто добавить `ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)` после создания всех процессов? Или прописать для каждого thread-а `.start()` и после `ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)`? Можете, если не сложно привести малейший пример с моего кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте пул потоков. Он сам создает потоки и контролирует их количество, вам нужно только передать ему функции на выполенение. А он сам поставит функцию в очередь пока не осовободится поток:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    futures = []
    for f in [func1, func2, func3, func4, func5]:
        futures.append(executor.submit(f))
    
    # ждем, когда закончат выполняться задачи
    for future in futures:
        future.result()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!